# 18.04: when changing region / language twice, I can start nautilus - otherwise not

Tags: nautilus, gnome-terminal, 18.04, language-support

I can't start Nautilus and Terminal and I need to type in my password when starting Chrome to access the password keyring.

When I go to Settings / Region & Language and change the Language from English (US) to English (GB) and then logout, login again and change the Language back to English (US) and logout / login again, I can start Terminal/Nautilus exactly once again.

After that I have to repeat this procedure to be able to start them again.

[image]

This is the output when starting the apps works:

The output of `locale`

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

The output of `cat /etc/default/locale`

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
```

This is the output when starting the apps doesn't work:

The output of `locale`

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

The output of `cat /etc/default/locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
```

Looks quite similar...

Comment: This sounds very confusing. Which language are you talking about? The display language or the keyboard layout?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I updated the original question.

Comment: Ok.. Can you please edit your question again and show us what these two commands output: 1. `locale` 2. `cat /etc/default/locale`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I updated the question again.

Comment: Looks quite normal, which makes it very odd that switching the language back and forth makes a difference. I'm out of ideas for now.